# Pytorch 0.2.1をバージョンダウンする方法

Tags: python3, 機械学習, pip, pytorch

#### 困っていること

下記の問題のgithubでget_dataset.py、data_util.py、train.pyを実行した結果、

```
RuntimeError: dimension specified as 0 but tensor has no dimensions
```

と出力されます。

[get_dataset.py](https://github.com/pytry3g/pytorch-example/blob/master/nlp/rnn/wikipedia/get_dataset.py)
では、
`re.findall("<p>.*</p>", html)`の部分を

`re.findall("<p>.+?</p>", html, re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)`

と直す必要があるようです。

[エラーが出ているgithubのリンク](https://github.com/pytry3g/pytorch-example/tree/master/nlp/rnn/wikipedia)

[githubを掲載しているサイト](https://www.pytry3g.com/entry/2018/03/16/203414)

[過去のteratailで問題のgithubを質問したリンク](https://teratail.com/questions/146993)

[pytorchのバージョンダウンをすすめる例](http://forums.fast.ai/t/dimension-out-of-range-error-during-training-in-pytorch-translate-ipynb/4673)

このような問題を解決するため、pytorchのバージョンダウンを行いたいと考えています。
しかし、pytorchは、torchとtorchvisionの両方があるため、どのようにインストールすればよいのか分かりません。
できれば、pipまたは、pip3でインストールを行いたいです。

何卒、よろしくお願いいたします。

#### 環境

Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS (x86_64)
Python 3.6.6
torch         0.4.1
torchvision   0.2.1
mecab-python3   0.7

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/151847

Answer (score 1):

まず、torchとtorchvisionをアンインストールします

```
pip3 uninstall torch torchvision
```

次に、torchを [INSTALLING PREVIOUS VERSIONS OF PYTORCH](https://pytorch.org/get-started/previous-versions/)のページに従って適当なバージョンのtorchをインストールします。以下は例です。

```
pip3 install http://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu80/torch-0.4.0-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl
```

その次に、torchvisionをバージョンを指定してインストールします。バージョンは例で、適当なバージョンを指定してインストールしてください。

```
pip3 install torchvision==0.2.0
```

Comment: ありがとうございました。なんとかcpuで動きました。
どうやら、torchvisionは、新しいバージョンをインストールすると、torchも新しくなってしまうようです。